# node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no default export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Trying to convert a React app over into Typescript and running into strange errors.

> node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no default export.
>
> node_modules/@types/react-dom/index"' has no default export.

I have my tsconfig and webpack setup for typescript. After changing this one component's extension from `.js` to `.tsx` I'm getting errors for React?

[image]

Thoughts?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./moonholdings/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "./app/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**webpack**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';
import chalk from 'chalk';

const moonholdings = path.resolve(__dirname, 'moonholdings');
const app = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');
const nodeModules = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.join(__dirname, '/app/index.html'),
  inject: 'body'
});

const ExtractTextPluginConfig = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'moonholdings.css',
  disable: false,
  allChunks: true
});

const CopyWebpackPluginConfigOptions = [{
  from: 'app/static',
  to: 'static/'
}];

const CopyWebpackPluginConfig = new CopyWebpackPlugin(CopyWebpackPluginConfigOptions);

const PATHS = {
  app,
  build: moonholdings
};

const LAUNCH_COMMAND = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

const isProduction = LAUNCH_COMMAND === 'production';
process.env.BABEL_ENV = LAUNCH_COMMAND;

const productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
});

const base = {
  // entry: ['babel-polyfill', PATHS.app],
  entry: './app/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [app, nodeModules],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
      },
      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      { enforce: 'pre', test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader' }
    ]
  }
};

const developmentConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: moonholdings
  },
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
  ]
};

const productionConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    productionPlugin
  ]
};

console.log(`${chalk.magenta('฿')} ${chalk.green('yarn run:')} ${chalk.red(LAUNCH_COMMAND)}`);

export default Object.assign(
  {}, base,
  isProduction === true ? productionConfig : developmentConfig
);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to use `import * as React from "react";` instead of `import React from 'react'`.

That happens because babel (the one that you were using before) assumes modules.export as default export while typescript (the one that you are using now) does not.

Answer (score 51):

You can use this syntax by simply adding `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` and `"esModuleInterop":true` to your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Very good!! this will also solve all issues with "has no default export."

Comment: According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54674521/416714) as of TypeScript 2.7 the option you need to add is `"esModuleInterop": true`.

Comment: This should be the top answer. This solves issues when you want to import types along with the default - which you cannot do using the `* as React` method.

Comment: `"esModuleInterop": true` option alone is enough.

Comment: This should be the best answer. I've seen many people suggesting modifying the import statements which I think is the wrong move here.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue while using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and found out it's possible to simply omit the `import` declaration in this case. A component like the following would have the first line removed.

```
import React from "react"; // Delete this line

function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div>MyComponent</div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

It's still possible to import components, hooks, etc. from React if needed, e.g.:

```
import { useState } from "react";
```

Notice I already had the options describe in [GoalsAndGambles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479609/1128918) added to my `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

For any future dev this was caused by the `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` extension for me in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `react-shim.js` file at project root with following content:

```js
import * as React from "react";
export { React };
```