# React with TypeScript - how to import methods

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In React with TypeScript I gather you import using `import * as React from 'react';`.

If I'm wanting to use `useState` and `Fragment` for example, I know I could just use `React.useState` and `React.Fragment`. However, is there any way to destructure those in the import? I know without TypeScript you'd do...

`import react, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';`

Would you have to do two imports instead, like....

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
```

Or would that import those twice? Seems a bit clunky too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of TypeScript 2.7, you can turn on `esModuleInterop` in your .tsconfig file in order to make imports work like they do in normal JavaScript. This is disabled by default for backwards compatibility reasons, but the [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html) say:

> We highly recommend applying it both to new and existing projects.

Comment: This is a great tip, Thanks Joe 

Answer (score 3):

Add these options to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

And then you can do:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
```

Comment: I don't think you need both - just `esModuleInterop` should work on newer versions of TypeScript. As far as I understand it, `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` just disables the error (forcing you to rely on a module loader/bundler to emit the compatibility code), whereas `esModuleInterop` will work even if you're just using TypeScript alone.

Comment: Aha, I just looked at the [list of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) - apparently `esModuleInterop` implicitly enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`. So you don't need to specify it, but it won't hurt to do so either :)